# How to remove WS_EX_TOPMOST style from window?

Tags: c

I try to create Window for video by using following syntax:

```
hwnd=CreateWindow("Video Window", "Video window", 
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rect.right-rect.left,rect.bottom-rect.top,        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

All works as expected but the issue is that the window always on top. It means that I see this window even if I switch to other application.

From `Window directive` program I found additional style: `WS_EX_TOPMOST`

[image]

How can I remove It programmatically or do I need override it somehow?

I tried `SetWindowPos`:

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

or to use instead `CreateWindow` at `CreateWindowEx`:

```
hwnd=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
                    "Video Window","Video Window",
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW  | WS_VISIBLE ,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    rect.right-rect.left,
                    rect.bottom-rect.top,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    hInstance,
                    NULL);
```

but still get flag `WS_EX_TOPMOST`

Thanks,

Comment: Clearly the window you are looking at is not the window that *you* created.  Not unusual if you play back video with some kind of library.  Why it would create a topmost window is unguessable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of going about it is to query the window for it's current extended-style, before clearing the bits that correspond to WS_EX_TOPMOST and setting the new extended style.

Something like this:

```
long dwExStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
dwExStyle &= ~WS_EX_TOPMOST;
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, dwExStyle);
```

Comment: The documentation for the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` [Extended Window Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) implies that it should be added/removed using [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx).

Comment: On Windows 7 I wasn't able to add/remove WS_EX_TOPMOST using GetWindowLong/SetWindowLong, but your suggestion with SetWindowPos worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
::SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0,  SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```